# calculate the distinct number of users who have a certain value in all the fields in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner in power BI. So, excuse me if this is a basic question.

I have data like this:

```
User1 - Task A - Complete
User1 - Task B - InComplete
User1 - Task C - Complete
User 2 - Task A - Complete
User 2 - Task B - Complete
User 2 - Task C - Complete
```

Now, I want to get the number of distinct users in the list who have completed all the tasks in power BI. So, for the above example, there is only one user(User2) who have completed all three tasks. I have 7 such tasks and thousands of users, how do i get the number of distinct users that completed all the tasks, something like a DAX formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
Users with 7 complete tasks =
COUNROWS ( // This counts rows in a table.
  FILTER ( // Filter takes a table and a predicate. It returns only rows that match the
           // predicate.
    VALUES ( 'Table'[User] ), // list of unique users in context
    // Below, we calculate the rows for the current user where 'Table'[Status] is
    // complete. I'm making an assumption on column names. The count will be 7
    // iff the user has 7 rows with 'Table'[Status]="Complete".
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Status] = "Complete" ) = 7
  )
)
```

The `COUNTROWS` will return 1 or BLANK for a specific user. It will return a count of users meeting the criterion of 7 complete tasks for totals.